# jQuery/Javascript : How to get the nth pair in a group of pairs?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo, getjson

Got a `$.getJSON` results from `MySql` `SELECT` Query via `PHP_PDO: fetchAssoc` `echo`ed with `json_encode()`, the output goes like this in firebug console:

```
//Console.log shows
            [Object { user_id="10", user_age="80", user_name="Adam"}, 
             Object { user_id="11", user_age="70", user_name="Eve"},
             Object { user_id="12", user_age="60", user_name="Cain"},
             Object { user_id="13", user_age="30", user_name="Abel"},
             Object { user_id="14", user_age="180",user_name="Satan"}]
```

Please note that this is being viewed as `console.log(result)`, however, in javascript's interpretation, this will be something like: `user_id:"10"`, `user_age:"80"` etc... replacing the `"="` with `":"` to form `key:value` pairs .

Now, how does one extract something like the 4th object's `user_name` from this kind of a result and have an alert like `alert( to out put: 'Abel')`?

Comment: Can you explain a little more, don't understand what do you want

Comment: its an array, if u know which index u want to look for just go for: alert(myArra[3].user_age)

Comment: To get 4th objects user_name you can just write result[3].user_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you right, you have a variable 'result' with type of Array, and every item in your Array has type of Object. So, you can just get an element with index and then access to property you need:

```
result[3].user_name
```

Comment: Cool, Boss... Worked like VOODOO!.  thanks for the timely reminder on associative arrays__the javascript style.